# PowerShell - escaping fancy single and double quotes for regex and string replace

Tags: powershell

I'm working with HTML files created by Acrobat, which doesn't use proper HTML entities to escape Unicode characters. I need to include single and double right quotation marks in a regex pattern, but every attempt I've made at escaping these characters has failed in my script...even if it works from a regular PowerShell session.

For example, this find/replace does not work:

```ps
    $html = $html.Replace("`“", '&ldquo;')
    $html = $html.Replace("`”", '&rdquo;')
    $html = $html.Replace("`‘", '&lsquo;')
    $html = $html.Replace("`’", '&rsquo;')
```

...but it *does* work if I break into my script and run one of those replace lines from the debug prompt.

Edit:
Here's a snippet of the markup I'm testing with right now:

```html
<p style="padding-left: 5pt;text-indent: 17pt;line-height: 119%;text-align: justify;">To guide its readers the Hermetica makes use of the mystical astrological world-view that we have been discussing. It describes the creation of the world as a series of emanations, starting with the Light, who gave birth to a son called Logos. In the words of Hermes’s guide, Poimandres:</p><p style="padding-left: 24pt;text-indent: 0pt;line-height: 119%;text-align: justify;">“That Light,” he said, “is I, even Mind, the first God, who was before the watery substance which appeared out of the darkness; and the Logos which came forth the Light is son of God.”</p><p style="padding-left: 21pt;text-indent: 1pt;line-height: 119%;text-align: justify;">(Scott, Walter, translator, Hermetica: The Ancient Greek and Latin Writings Which Contain Religious or Philosophical Teachings Ascribed to Hermes Trismegistus, Boston: Shambhala: 1985, p. 117)</p>
```

If `$html` equals that string, my attempts to find and replace the characters appear to be futile.

Comment: The snippet you posted seems to work, which makes me think there's something else going on in a part of your script that you didn't include.

Comment: Hmmm. $html is just the contents of an Acrobat-generated HTML file, and this is early into the parsing of the file, so I haven't done much to it. If I output the contents of $html at a debug prompt (in VSCode), I still see the Unicode quote characters, not the HTML entities - same goes for outputting $html to a text file so I can see the result.

Comment: I'm getting correct results from a non-VSCode PowerShell window, so this might be something specific to VSCode's PowerShell extension.

Comment: It's very possible. I've only ever used PowerShell ISE so I couldn't say one way or the other.

Comment: Ok, this seems to be an issue with the encoding of my .ps1 file. A test script I created in the ISE was saved as UTF-8 BOM, whereas VSCode creates UTF8 files without the BOM. The ISE-created test with BOM encoding works; the *exact same code* saved as UTF8 in VSCode does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently, PowerShell does funny things with non-BOM UTF-8 encoding. [Setting VSCode to auto-encode PowerShell scripts as UTF-8 with BOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/vscode/understanding-file-encoding?view=powershell-7.2) allows the String.Replace function to operate as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Unicode values instead of backquoting the literal:

```
    $html = $html.Replace("`u{201C}", '&ldquo;')
    $html = $html.Replace("`u{201D}", '&rdquo;')
    $html = $html.Replace("`u{2018}", '&lsquo;')
    $html = $html.Replace("`u{2019}", '&rsquo;')
```

Produces

[image]

If you're having problems with encoding (UTF-8, for example, as you suggested), take a look at https://unicode-table.com - you can get the code values for any encoding.

Comment: First one worked for me :) nice answer

Comment: That format for Unicode entities isn't working at all for me.